# How can I run an Intel-based macOS in a virtual environment to test my app?

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware, intel

I am a developer. I've written a native app for macOS on my MacBook Air (with the Apple M2 chip.) Now I need to test it for an Intel-based CPU. When I build my app in Xcode, it is supposed to cover both ARM64 and x86-64 architectures in a single Mach-O binary, but when I send it to my customer he tells me that the app works on the Apple silicon but it crashes on his Intel-based Mac. So I'm looking for ways to test-run my app on an Intel-based platform and see what is wrong there. (But I obviously don't want to buy a separate Mac just for that.)

I know that one can use Azure to spin up a Windows, or a Linux VM and open it via a web browser. But it doesn't seem to support macOS.

How can I run an Intel-based macOS in a virtual environment?

Comment: The answer (on the linked question) seems to be "No". However, you should ask your customer for crash logs, to see if that gives you any help.

Comment: @benwiggy yeah, as always SO is more concerned about closing questions than answering them. But anyway, I tried to get a crash log, but didn't succeed. For me, it's always better to try it out on my dev machine than to bug the customer. So going back to the question, apart from buying the Intel-based hardware, there seems to be Rosetta that may help. But it's not a perfect solution.